# Why is my Close-Vote queue for a tag empty?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I'm one of those <del>fools</del>^<sup>users</sup> who spends most or all of their close-votes daily. As part of the efforts of the [SO Close Vote Review Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), we coordinate on reviewing particular tags to reduce their backlogs.

I've run into a bit of weirdness. Maybe there's a bug. Maybe there is more to the documented rules than I know; perhaps after you've voted once on a question it won't be in **your** queue after your vote ages off.

> Edits or a sufficient number of "Leave Open" reviews will remove the question from review and immediately begin aging the close votes. If the question receives another close vote after being kicked out, it will re-enter the queue for further review. [<sub>Reviewing close and reopen votes</sub>](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

I interpret that to mean that any question that has received a close vote after being "kicked out" of the queue should be *in the queue*.

But that's not what I see. Note that I'm including question links here just to facilitate any digging that someone with super-powers may need to do.

For me, the [cv queue for my target tag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=3rd-party%20third-party) is empty. However, if I go through the [open questions on that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bthird-party%5D%20closed%3A0%20answers%3A1..), I can find questions that have close votes on them, and that I'm allowed to place a close vote on. (I know that at least a couple of these got "left open" via the general CVRQ, and then got new close votes.)

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/9253934/1677912
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23796512/1677912
- [How do I use function from external library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15271426/1677912)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/21378044/1677912 (closed before I could re-vote)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/13234683/1677912
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/28075971/1677912

Since I am able to vote on them, I would expect to see those in the tag close-vote review queue. Why don't I?

In contrast, there are other open questions that are understandably missing, such as these ones that I voted on several weeks ago but are still open, and I can't vote on again for at least another week:

- [One-time login tokens for third-party access to a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9299932/1677912)
- [Third Party Polymer Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22737561/1677912)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/6121212/1677912

There have been other questions of a similar vein:

- [When do questions appear on the “Close Vote” review queue?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1472/when-do-questions-appear-on-the-close-vote-review-queue) (Mathematica)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably related to these questions getting kicked out of the review queue by three Leave Open votes.

Here are some review tasks for four of these questions:

- [How do I use function from external library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15271426/1768232)

  - [One Close, three Leave Open votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9534752)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/28075971/1768232

  - [Two Close, three Leave Open votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9534676)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23796512/1768232

  - [Two Close, three Leave Open votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9534749)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/13234683/1768232

  - [Two Close, three Leave Open votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9534499)

I stopped at four before getting bored. It seems to me that once a post gets three leave open reviews, it's not going to appear for you, even if it receives another close vote later. I'm fairly confident that this behavior is by design.

Comment: If this **is** by design, it's clearly only on SO; I know on other sites that I have CV, questions get added back in with a new review entry if they pick up another close vote after being kicked out. (That is, they keep their close vote totals but start fresh with a blank review entry that has no votes of any kind in its record.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Perhaps the close vote occurred before the review task was completed, I can't easily look that information up.

Comment: I appreciate the extra digging - I got bored faster, once I saw that a couple of questions had been through the "leave open" path, I assumed the rest had. I'm also pretty sure that (on SO at least) your guess is right, and that's the mechanism squelching the questions from my review queue. However, it's not consistent with the documented behaviour, and (as we both know from the [SOCVR Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) discussion), it is a speed bump in the burnination process. I'd love to hear from a dev or other insider.